# Failing to copy ssh key to clipboard

Tags: linux, github, ssh, virtual-machine

I'm trying to copy an `ssh` key from my Linux VM but whenever I type

```
xclip -sel < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
```

I am prompted with:

```
Error: Can't display: (null)
```

I've  been trying to follow https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/#platform-linux

Comment: It depends on what Linux are you using, if you have graphical interface, what virtualization and so on. Certainly you tried the note on the linked page that solve your problem, but you are just curios?

Comment: There is no graphical interface & I am running Ubuntu (64-bit). Without a graphical interface how would it be possible to follow that note on the linked page?

Comment: This command will save the SSH key in clipboard only you need to paste at the desired location

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy

Answer (score 0):

Tools that start with X are usually related to Xorg graphical system. If you have only console access to virtual machine, `xclip` will obviously not allow you to copy to your system clipboard. It would be possible with some *DE and some extensions.

> Tip: If xclip isn't working, you can locate the hidden .ssh folder, open the file in your favorite text editor, and copy it to your clipboard.

Just transfer (`scp`, FileZilla, whatever you prefer) the file to your host system and open it in your favorite editor as the Tip above suggests. And copy from there.

Comment: Any tutorial for transferring files from Linux VM to Windows Host?

Comment: as i already mentioned, read about sftp and filezilla. it should do the job